# Ideas to improve my AQL query

Tags: database, graph, arangodb, aql

In my graph, a user is connected to many items and each item can be recursively divided into many sub-items. Since my items have a particular ordering, I'm considering these two options to model my data:

[image]

Now I want to create a query to retrieve two levels of items for a given userID. This AQL is my first attempt:

```
for itemId in (for b in board filter b._from == @_from sort b.order return b._to)
    for item1 in (for t in item filter t._id == itemId return keep(t, '_id', 'title'))
        return merge(item1, {board: (
            for itemId2 in (for b in board filter b._from == item1._id sort b.order return b._to)
                for t in item filter t._id == itemId2 return keep(t, '_id', 'title')
        )})
```

The query works and it outputs a result like this:

```
[
  {
    "title": "item 1",
    "_id": "item/41260117498",
    "board": [
      {
        "title": "item 4",
        "_id": "item/42205736442"
      },
      {
        "title": "item 5",
        "_id": "item/42208423418"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "item 2",
    "_id": "item/41260772858",
    "board": []
  },
  {
    "title": "item 3",
    "_id": "item/41883233786",
    "board": []
  }
]
```

Which is fine, but I feel like my query is unnecessarily complex for such a simple traversal. Could someone help me to create a better one, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point in using a [graph database](https://docs.arangodb.com/Graphs/) is utilize its graph querying capabilities letting it handle the edges, and not to do it on your own by manually joining the edges.

I will demonstrate the [pattern matching traversals](https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/GraphTraversals.html) for such a query; they handle the transision over the edges (`_from` and `_to`) transparently under the hood for you.

First you would [create a graph](https://docs.arangodb.com/GeneralGraphs/Management.html) to configure your edge relations, we use an anonymous graph for simplicity. You have the edge collection `board` and the vertex collections `user` and `item`.

First you simply let run the whole query to get a feeling for how it works, and inspect the full result:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 1..3 OUTBOUND 'user/andy' board RETURN {v: v, e: e, p: p}
```

You see that you only need to specify the start node, and the edge collection `board`, it will find the vertex collections to query on its own by inspecting the edges.

Now we may add `FILTER`s to omit edges and vertices that we don't like:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 1..3 OUTBOUND 'user/andy' board 
   FILTER e.title == 'item 2'
   FILTER p.edges[1].title != 'item 1'
   RETURN {v: v, e: e, p: p}
```

The example contains two `FILTER` instructions; one is matching each edge to have the `title` attribute being equal `"item 2"`, the other is matching that the first edge in the traversal has to contain `title` `"item 1"`.

Finaly we [use document manipulation](https://docs.arangodb.com/Documents/index.html) to only get the parts of the documents we like:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 1..3 OUTBOUND 'user/andy' board 
   FILTER e.title == 'item 2' 
   RETURN {v: v, e: {title: e.title, _id: e._id}, pathEdgeTitle: p.edges[*].title}
```